# Draw a rectangle on loglogaxis

Tags: pgfplots

I need to represent a certain area on the plot, I thought drawing a rectangle would be the easiest. But other means could work too, I just don't know.

Expected result:
[image: plot with a red rectangle]

I am clearly doing something wrong here.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document} 
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \bigskip
    

    \begin{loglogaxis}[
        minor y tick num=4,
        minor x tick num=4,
        height={},
        xmin=0,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=1000000,
        xmax=1000,
        %xtickten={0.001,1},
        legend cell align=left,
        legend pos=north east,
        ]
        \addplot [mark=*,only marks] coordinates {(126.263,1.07)};
        \draw [red] (axis cs:5,0) rectangle (axis cs:30,10) ;
%       \draw [blue] (5,0) rectangle (30,10) ;
    \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't really much wrong with your `\draw`, but if you look in the `.log` file you get a hint to where the problem lies:

```
Package pgfplots Warning: Ignoring illegal input argument xmin=0: cannot apply 
log. on input line 22.


Package pgfplots Warning: Ignoring illegal input argument ymin=0: cannot apply 
log. on input line 22.
```

I.e., the `xmin` and `ymin` settings are ignored, and the lower limits therefore depend on the data present in the plot, and that one data point is nowhere near the rectangle. Add `clip=false` to the `axis` options and you'll see that rectangle ends up outside the axis. I don't know exactly how the zero-value for the first y-coordinate is interpreted, but zero doesn't really make sense here anyway ...

[image]

Set those lower axis limits to some useful value larger than zero, and they will be applied:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document} 
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \bigskip
    

    \begin{loglogaxis}[
        minor y tick num=4,
        minor x tick num=4,
        height={},
        xmin=1, % <-- modified
        ymin=0.1, % <-- modified
        ymax=1000000,
        xmax=1000,
        %xtickten={0.001,1},
        legend cell align=left,
        legend pos=north east,clip=false
        ]
        \addplot [mark=*,only marks] coordinates {(126.263,1.07)};

        \draw [red] (axis cs:5,0.2) rectangle (axis cs:30,10);
        % because you have compat=1.16, axis cs: is not required, and this does the same:
        % \draw [red] (5,0.2) rectangle (30,10);
    \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `axis description cs` coordinate system, where each axis goes from 0 to 1.  So,

```
\draw [red, ultra thick] (axis description cs:0.15,0) rectangle (axis description cs:0.45,0.30) ;
```

producess the red rectangle.

[image]

If you want to stick with the `axis cs` coordinate system, then you need to use the actual coordinates of the points. So something like:

```
\draw [blue] (axis cs:140,0.1) rectangle (axis cs:300,100) ;
```

draws the blue rectangle.

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document} 
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{loglogaxis}[
        minor y tick num=4,
        minor x tick num=4,
        height={},
        xmin=0,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=1000000,
        xmax=1000,
        %xtickten={0.001,1},
        legend cell align=left,
        legend pos=north east,
        ]
        \addplot [mark=*,only marks] coordinates {(126.263,1.07)};
        \draw [red, ultra thick] (axis description cs:0.15,0) rectangle (axis description cs:0.45,0.30) ;
        \draw [blue, ultra thick] (axis cs:140,0.1) rectangle (axis cs:300,100) ;
    \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```